# jQuery If dropdown is selected

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, selected

I am trying to create a jQuery function that should only run if dropdown wc-completed is selected in dropdown on WooCommerce order page. Basically, I want a field to be required before an order can be completed.

I've tried with some if statement but I am not sure on how to tell jQuery it should only run if wc-completed is selected in dropdown menu. Should I use change function instead?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if ($("select#order_status option:selected").val() === "wc-completed" && !$("body").hasClass("post-type-shop_order")) { 
    $("input#wcam-external-link-0").prop('required',true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have only runs on page load so yes you should use a change event listener

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("select#order_status").change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "wc-completed" && !$("body").hasClass("post-type-shop_order")) {
        $("input#wcam-external-link-0").prop('required', true);
      }

    })
    // optional -- trigger change on page load
    .change()

});
```